# EmbeddedDataSource cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jsp

I am trying to edit a red5 admin.jsp file to then add to the root folder of webapps. I am doing this so I can set user and password, but when all I get is unable to compile error.

> ```
> An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /admin.jsp
>   EmbeddedDataSource cannot be resolved to a type
> 16: try {
> 17: Object o = null;
> 18: if (o == null) {
> 19: EmbeddedDataSource eds = new EmbeddedDataSource();
> 20: eds.setCreateDatabase("name");
> 21: eds.setDatabaseName("user");
> 22: eds.setPassword("pass");
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added  derby-[version].jar to you lib direcory.
If already

```
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource;
```

Comment: Where would that lib directory be? please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Charlie Bunt "YourContext/WEB-INF/lib". You have to put derby jar file in the "lib" directory.